# help on understanding the definition of a topology, I read some other posts but I'm still confused.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

I am having trouble of fully understand the definition of topology, so I wonder if someone could explain why a $\sigma$-algebra is not necessarily a topology.

**Definition of topology:** A topology on a set $X$ is a collection $\tau$ of subsets of $X$ such that (1) $\emptyset$ and $X$ are in $\tau$; (2) Any union of subsets in $\tau$ is in $\tau$; (3) The finite intersection of subsets in $\tau$ is in $\tau$.

**Definition of a $\sigma$-algebra:** A $\sigma$-algebra on a set $X$ is a collection $S$ of subsets of $X$ such that (1) $\emptyset$, $X\in S$; (2) if $s\in S$ then $s^c\in S$; (3)if $s_i\in S$ for $i\in\mathbb{N}$ then $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty s_i\in S$, $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty s_i\in S$.

To me, it seems like (1) in both definitions are the same, and (2) (3) conditions in the definition of topology is included in (3) in the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra. Is this true?

Comment: Topologies are closed under **arbitrary** unions (not necessarily countable); $\sigma$-algebras need not be. Conversely, $\sigma$-algebras are closed under complements; topologies need not be.

Comment: @Bungo Thank you! Would that be the only difference such that the concept of topologies is more general than sigma algebra?

Comment: Neither concept is more general. There are topologies that are not $\sigma$-algebras, and vice versa. The answer by Primes gives an example of a $\sigma$-algebra that is not a topology. And the usual topology on $\mathbb R$ is a topology which is not a $\sigma$-algebra since it isn't closed under complements. (However, there is a minimal $\sigma$-algebra, namely the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, which contains the usual topology on $\mathbb R$.)

Comment: @Bungo Sorry that I didn't present my question well. I meant condition wise  , would that be the only condition that topology is more general? I didn't mean the definition of toplogy being more general.

Comment: The requirement that a topology is closed under arbitrary unions is more restrictive than the requirement that a $\sigma$-algebra is only closed under countable unions. On the other hand, the requirement that a $\sigma$-algebra is closed under complements and under countable intersections is more restrictive than the requirement that a topology is closed under finite intersections. I'm not sure if this answers your question or what you mean by "more general".

Comment: @Bungo Thank you very much! that answers my question precisely!

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample: Borel sets in $[0,1]$: σ-algebra, not topology (contains all points but not all subsets).